# Handle Parent Element Click in Child Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, ref

Basically, I have a group of pages that usually show up in a modal, but might not. I have a `Manager` component that handles going between them through the specific flow we need. I have a back button in the header of the `MyModal` component though, that when clicked I need to somehow tell the `Manager` to go back a page. But, the `Manager` doesn't know anything about the back button, and neither do the pages

**QUESTION:** How can I send an event or do something else to the `Manager` component so that it knows to go back a page when I click the `BackButton`?

Here's some example code.

```
const MyModal: React.FC = ({show, onHide}) => (
    <Modal show={show} onHide={onHide}>
        <BackButton onClick={/* What do I do here? */}/>
        <Modal.Body>
            <Manager {/* Do I put something here? */}/>
        </Modal.Body>
    </Modal>
);
```

```
const Manager: React.FC = () => {
    const [page, setPage]: [number, (d: number) => void] = useState(0);

    return (
        <>
            {[
                <Page1 onComplete={() => setPage(1)}/>
                <Page2 onComplete={() => setPage(2)}/>
                <Page3 onComplete={() => setPage(1)} onCancel={() => setPage(3)/>
                <Page4 onComplete={() => setPage(4)}/>
                <Page5 onComplete={() => setPage(1)}/>
            ][page]}
        </>
    );
};
```

P.S. The `Modal` and `Modal.Body` come from react-bootstrap. I thought it illustrated the idea better to keep them in.

**Thoughts I've had:** I understand that I could just smush the two together into one component, and that would be fine in most cases, but I'm wondering if this specifically is possible. To have the action fire in a separate component, if that makes sense. I've wondered about using `ref`'s somehow, but I have read a bunch about them, and I'm still confused. I thought I could somehow pass a `ref` to the button into the `Manager` component, but I couldn't get that to work.

Comment: can you pass `setPage` to the Page components so they can set the page when you hit the back button?

Comment: They don't know anything about the back button either. The back button is in the wrapping component. I'll clarify my question.

Comment: Ah, I see. Then yes, you should life your state up to the highest component that needs it. In this case if that's `MyModal`, then the `page` state and `setPage` dispatcher should be in the modal

Comment: I might end up doing that actually. I'll leave the question as is though, to see if anyone can tell me how to do specifically what I'm asking. I feel like there has to be some way to do it, maybe with refs or something?

Comment: And if you use context hook? You can share information between connected components. :D